# JNLP extracting files from jar

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

This is my jar file :
[image: jar file]

When I run my code(below) with my jar `java -jar myprogram.jar` it extracts the file from jar(Jar does what I need)

```
List<Path> result = this.getPathsFromResourceJAR("tokenconfig.json");
for (Path path : result) {
    String filePathInJAR = path.toString();
    if (filePathInJAR.startsWith("/")) {
        filePathInJAR = filePathInJAR.substring(1, filePathInJAR.length());
    }
    System.out.println("filePathInJAR : " + filePathInJAR);
    // read a file from resource folder
    InputStream is = this.getFileFromResourceAsStream(filePathInJAR);
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, new File(filePathInJAR) );
}          

// get a file from the resources folder
// works everywhere, IDEA, unit test and JAR file.
private InputStream getFileFromResourceAsStream(String fileName) {

    // The class loader that loaded the class
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    // the stream holding the file content
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("file not found! " + fileName);
    } else {
        return inputStream;
    }

}

// Get all paths from a folder that inside the JAR file
private List<Path> getPathsFromResourceJAR(String folder)
    throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    List<Path> result;
    // get path of the current running JAR
    String jarPath = getClass().getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource()
            .getLocation()
            .toURI()
            .getPath();
    System.out.println("JAR Path :" + jarPath);

    // file walks JAR
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + jarPath);
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap())) {
        result = Files.walk(fs.getPath(folder)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is my jnlp file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/bsign/" href="bsign.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Testing</title>
        <vendor>bermuda</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/bsign/" />
        <description>jnlp Testing</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="bsignclient.jar" />

        <jar href="libs/commons-discovery-0.2.jar" />
        <jar href="libs/commons-io-2.8.0.jar" />
        <jar href="libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
        .
        .
        .

    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.bermuda.App" />
</jnlp>
```

When I try to run from jnlp I get this error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: C:\bsign\bsignclient.jar
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:120)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:117)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
    at com.bermuda.helpers.FileHelper.getPathsFromResourceJAR(FileHelper.java:138)
    at com.bermuda.helpers.FileHelper.extractResources(FileHelper.java:46)
    at com.bermuda.ui.MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:54)
    at com.bermuda.ui.SysTray.<init>(SysTray.java:72)
    at com.bermuda.App.main(App.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

from console:

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://localhost:8080/bsign/bsignclient.jar
JAR Path :/bsign/bsignclient.jar
JAR Path :/bsign/bsignclient.jar
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### C:\bsign\bsignclient.jar
```

So when I put my jar here `C:\bsign\bsignclient.jar` it extracts the file. But this is not I need, I need to extract this file from jnlp. How should I do this extaction from jar?

Comment: *"How should I do this extaction from jar?"* Get an `URL` to the embedded-resource (whether it's still in a Jar or not, is treated the same way by web-start), get an `InputStream` for the `URL`. Get an output stream for a `File`. Red the bytes of the input stream and write them to the output stream. Flush the output stream and close both. /Fin

Comment: BTW - JWS was removed in Java 9, so I'm guessing you're using an older JRE. I'm surprised enough of the potential users have old enough JREs to run this stuff, or old enough browsers to launch it.

Comment: I am using Java 8, if users are using newer versions there is [open web start](https://openwebstart.com/) .

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did it with `URL -> InputStream` jnlp stays the same(Asks for `C:\bsign\bsignclient.jar`), and also jar is not working `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 25: C:/Users/Mali/Desktop/run desktop/bsign.jar/tokenconfig.json` it gets the correct path but it can't write

Comment: That comment suggests you are very confused. Post the code that produces the stated results.

Comment: @AndrewThompson firstly thanks for your help, I tried to access with `http://localhost:8080/bsign/bsignclientjava.jar/tokenconfig.json` but I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`  now I made a folder for resources, I am accessing them with embedded `URL` like you suggested, now my jar also has less folders. I have another [question] ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538810/jnlp-running-dependency-librarys-functions)  I would be happy if you can look at it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put `tokenconfig.json` in my server inside resources folder.
I made an embeded URL like

`String path = "http://localhost:8080/bsign/resources/tokenconfig.json"`

```
    String path = "http://localhost:8080/bsign/resources/tokenconfig.json"
    downloadAndCopy(path);


    private void downloadAndCopy(String path){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);

            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            System.out.println("copying : " + path);

            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, new File(path));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```